# Getting error not exported by 'namespace:DOSE

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am getting this two errors. Can someone give quick solution for this error? I had also installed latest package, and still getting this error.

```
library(ReactomePA)
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ReactomePA’:
# object ‘netplot’ is not exported by 'namespace:DOSE'

yy = enrichPathway(gene, pvalueCutoff=0.05)
# Error in enrichPathway(gene, pvalueCutoff = 0.05) :
# could not find function "enrichPathway"

library(clusterProfiler)
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘clusterProfiler’:
# object ‘dotplot’ is not exported by 'namespace:DOSE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the packages and reinstalling:

```
remove.packages(c("ReactomePA", "clusterProfiler"))

source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

biocLite("ReactomePA")
biocLite("clusterProfiler")
```